# Fastest way to unlock custom special moves?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

Unlocking custom special moves by playing the Classic game seems to be slow and slightly random. Is there an easier way?

Comment: i recommend smash run but you got to pay attention to what items you pick up as you can only pick up 10 or so, so dont pick up any trophies!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Classic** mode is a good way to get special moves, and seems to be the fastest for the 3DS version of the game. You have a slight chance to get custom moves for any unlocked character (except Mii and Palutena, who start will all moves unlocked, and DLC characters, who don't have any custom moves), a higher chance to get custom moves for the characters you fight against, and the highest chance to get special moves for the character that you're playing as. Keep that in mind when selecting your character and each battle you pick. You can generally get more on higher difficulties, but you'll lose some rewards if you lose both lives on one stage. You can also use custom characters to make completing Classic mode faster and easier. On the 3DS, you can use a home button to temporarily freeze the spinner before each match, which makes getting custom upgrades, such as special moves, from the spinner easier.

**All-Star** mode on the Wii U version with the difficulty set to **Hard** is a great way to get moves for the specific character you're playing as, because completion of each round gives two rewards, special moves are often the rewards, and dying will not lose any rewards you've already earned. Unfortunately the 3DS version provides fewer rewards, and they are mostly trophies, so this is not a good way to earn special moves on the 3DS.

Another way to get special moves is to have an **Amiibo** fight computer players. Amiibos gather upgrades, including custom moves, when they fight. You can use this strategy to get new moves while away from the game.

On the Wii U version, you can also get special moves from **Special Orders**. Each special order you select gives a hint at what you'll receive for completing it. For a higher chance to get custom moves, select tickets that show something other than money or the Super Smash Bros icon.

Also on the Wii U version, you can do **Smash Tour** to get larger quantities of rewards, including special moves. The downsides to this are that it takes longer than the other methods to complete a single round, and that you have less control over the resulting rewards.

Comment: I've had an Amiibo play against computers quite a bit, and haven't noticed any custom moves acquired. Are they gathered silently without telling the player, or is there some other requirement for getting that to work?

Comment: You should be able to collect the rewards by going to the Amiibo section of the menu and scanning your Amiibo there.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I never actually went back to the "Amiibo" section; I'd just been using him in Smash mode for a while.

Comment: Yeah, using the Amiibo seems to work well. The chance of getting custom moves is a lot lower than getting equipment, but at least it's automatic.

Comment: Trophy Rush and Smash Run on the 3DS are also good ways to get custom moves. I have not found that the amiibos collect custom moves or equipment when they fight on the 3DS though.

Comment: @2rs2ts Interesting. I'm unable to test that myself because I don't have a New 3DS. Are you getting other items from them?

Comment: @Brian No, I'm getting nothing. It's just like playing against a CPU.

Comment: @2rs2ts You need to go to the Amiibo section of the menu to get the items.

Answer (score 4):

I only have the Wii U version. I've collected 97% of the collectable custom moves and 95% of the total custom moves. This is what I suspect to be the most efficient way to collect custom moves on the Wii U.

General info:

- Classic mode seems to favor giving R.O.B, Sonic, Donkey Kong, Diddy Kong, and Falco custom moves.
- Although people seem to enjoy bashing the trophy rush game, it is probably the most time efficient. I would suggest waiting until you've unlocked about 80% of the custom moves and acquired a massive amount of money because it is by far the least money efficient. Make sure that you use whatever character that you're trying to get custom moves for.
- If you are bad with a character, wait until you've collected about 80% of the custom moves and acquired some money. Then you will want to use the character that you are bad with in trophy rush, master orders, and crazy orders.
- In classic mode, the order of priority for what you are trying to get on the spinner should be as follows: Custom part, Crazy orders pass, and you can choose whether coins or trophies are more important to you.
- There are some custom moves that can only be unlocked by completing a challenge, use this website to check what challenges you need to complete in order to unlock custom moves: http://www.ssbwiki.com/List_of_challenges_(SSB4-Wii_U)

Step one: 
The first thing that you will want to do is create a table so that you can keep track of every character's custom moves.

Step two:
For the first 40% of unlockable custom moves I would suggest using mainly smash tour. For every two or three rounds of smash tour I would suggest playing one or two rounds of Classic mode (difficulty at least 3.5) or all-star mode (normal difficulty).

Step three:
Once you've collected 40% of the custom moves, I would suggest playing classic and all-star mode on the highest difficulty that you can manage with the characters that you're trying to unlock custom moves for. You can also start playing master orders and crazy orders with the characters that you're trying to unlock custom moves for.

Step four/custom moves for characters that you're bad with:
Once you've collected 80% of the custom moves, you will want to start using crazy orders, master orders, and trophy rush almost exclusively. You should be able to afford it if you've been saving up money and crazy order passes. If you ever feel like you're running low on money or passes, switch to classic and all-star for a while and focus on coins and passes.

Comment: I strongly advise against including your email address here. If you want to share a Google doc, you can give it a public URL and put a link to it instead.

Comment: It almost feels like you have a better chance of getting custom moves when you play a lower level of Classic. I've been playing 2.9 (the highest level without having to fight both hands) and it seems like I get 5-6 moves per run, whereas when I play 7.0 or something, I only get 2-3. YMMV

Comment: Also I've noticed that I get tons of R.O.B moves for some reason. I pretty much never play as him, and yet I "win" his moves all the time. It's quite annoying. I'm finally closing in though, just have Kirby, Jigglypuff, Game&Watch, and Toon Link left to get moves for.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what you mean by "easier" - there's no way to do it that's not random.

- Classic mode isn't that bad for custom moves if you use the Home trick on the roulette (press Home to pause and unpause, press A to stop once the wrench comes up, only works on 3DS version). But even then it's a bit slow, and if you fail at any point you lose a bunch of them.
- Smash Run (3DS only) is a bit faster but requires a bit more luck and effort (since you have to actually find the customs in chests or enemies and pick them up).
- Smash Tour (Wii U only) I hear isn't bad for number of rewards, but it takes quite a while to go through one "cycle".
- Crazy Orders (Wii U only) gives out a pretty good spectrum of rewards, and a lot of people like it, but it's ripe for frustration because of the lose-once-and-too-bad setup, and it's not cheap to play.
- All-Star Mode gives out 2-5 (or something) depending on difficulty, and you don't lose them if you fail.
- Trophy Rush doesn't give out any more than 1 custom part per Fever, so I don't think it's worth doing for that purpose.
- Target Blast can have customs but only one per run and you still have to hit it. Not worth it.
- If you have an amiibo, it collects rewards after battles, and I hear the payoff is pretty good (cannot confirm myself).

Of course, no matter what you do, you can't force the game to give you custom moves as opposed to equipment.

Comment: Trophy Rush at least for me seems to have a MUCH higher rate to give out moves for the character you are using than Classic has been. I don't know if it's a fact (and probably isn't) but I've played Classic with most of the characters and have gotten maybe 2 or 3 for the character I was currently using. But after a dozen Trophy Rushes only 2 have been for a character I wasn't using.

Comment: I've completed All-Star with all characters and never gotten more than 2 custom moves from it, even on hard.

Comment: The "home" trick does _not_ work on WiiU.

Comment: @Brian I got 5 new custom moves via All-Star just as a sanity check, so...maybe you're as unlucky as I am at Trophy Rush?

Comment: @Toomai On the Wii U or 3DS? I've done it on all characters on the 3DS and only a few on the Wii U.

Comment: Do you have to unlock Trophy Rush?

Comment: @Atav32 No, Trophy Rush is available from the start in both versions of the game.

Comment: It's not *truly* available from the start because you need cash to play it; this is in fact another reason why I don't like it, because you may want to save your money for trophies or Crazy Orders.

Comment: As an update to my previous comment about All-Star, it's great for getting special moves on Hard difficulty on the Wii U, but really inefficient on the 3DS.

Answer (score 1):

Whichever way you choose, it's going to take a long time to get every custom move.

For me, Master Orders is fastest. Every round you play costs a bit of money, but you always get a new piece of character specific equipment, or a new move. Sometimes, you get up to three per play (but I've never received more than 2 custom moves at once).

My character of choice for Master Orders is Ganondorf, because sometimes there are home run contests on Intense difficulty (1152 meters), and I haven't figured out how to hit that far with any of the other fighters.

Answer (score 0):

You can play trophy rush, sometime they will give you custom move and a lot of trophys.

Comment: Trophy Rush is a way to get custom moves, but it's one of the slowest, and costs money to do.

Comment: Might want to clarify that it costs in-game "gold" to do it, not actual real "money".

Answer (score 0):

When I have a ton of gold, I use DK with down-B hand slap on Trophy Rush, dodging every now and then to avoid the electric ball of death. Other than that, I do classic at 7.9 with the Home button trick to fight just Master Hand with the highest possible payout.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to do crazy orders. If you do only like 2 or 3 levels you should get decent amounts especially if you do tickets with lots of characters to fight, because if you defeat Crazy Hand, you'll get some customs for defeating characters. Trust me, this is a GREAT way to get customs.

Or just do trophy rush and get a lot of fever rushes.

Comment: Please don't re-edit your posts to stop using proper English.  Arqade has a higher standard than other sites out there, and having content that is clear and easy to understand is extremely important.

Answer (score 0):

whenever i played smash run on the 3ds, i usually got the specific moves for the character i was using and maybe a few other random ones. I don't know if this has been changed in recent updates, but the smash bros team would be stupid to change it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that they are more common on wiiU during classic because if your rival has custom you can fight them last and get 1 guaranteed move plus whatever else you got

Answer (score 0):

I am down to just 4 characters left to collect moves for (Kirby, Jigglypuff, Game&Watch, Toon Link)... so here is how I've gotten the moves so far:

-Lots of Smash Tour. The rewards seem to be random and unrelated to what actually happens, so just try to play it as quickly as possible. This means avoid battles at all costs and try to make sure everyone has as few fighters as possible for the final battle (to get it over with quickly). I've found that the Normal-sized map is the best for this, because everyone bumps into each other a lot on the Small-sized map, and the Big-sized map has a bunch of "battle spaces" that will start a battle if someone lands on it... and the CPU sure seems to love to land on those spots.

The game will also play Smash Tour by itself if you leave it alone. It takes a lot longer to do that because every single move has to wait for the timer to run out, but if you have other things to do, it's not a bad idea to just let it run and then collect the rewards when it is done. You usually get anywhere from 2-4 moves per tour, so this is a good way to get moves early on when you don't have many yet.

-Once you have a lot of moves, Smash Tour starts to become inefficient, so now you need to focus on Classic and Crazy Orders (some people say Master Orders too, but I almost never get custom moves there, so it seems like a waste of time). Classic depends on how well you can stop the spinner. Pretty much only pick battles where at least one fighter has the "red wrench" and then also try to stop the spinner on the red wrench as much as possible too. If you get lucky and your rival has a red wrench, wait until round 3 to fight them for maximum possibility of getting moves. If the rival does not have the red wrench, fight them in round 1 to get rid of them and make it easier to advance.

When you are playing in Classic, unfortunately a lot of the moves seem to be dependent on the map or opponents. You are more likely to get moves based on what map you play than you are based on who you are controlling. For example, let's say you are playing as Kirby and you select a match against a Bowser who has a red wrench icon on the stage Windy Hill Zone... if you stop the spinner on a red wrench you are most likely going to get a Sonic move (if you get any moves), since it is his level. If you KO Bowser, then you also have a decent chance at getting one of his moves as well. Alternatively, there is a slim chance you wind up with a Kirby move, and there is also a chance you get a random move, like R.O.B or something.

The best chance you have of actually getting moves for the character you are playing as is either from KOing a red-wrench rival, or from stopping the spinner on the wrench when you are on the last round, facing the hand(s). As far as I can tell, the level of intensity does not affect the distribution of custom moves. I have been playing regularly on both 2.9 and 7.0 and to be honest, it feels like I get more moves at 2.9 than I do at 7.0. The higher difficulties do give you more chances for red wrenches, but if you are good at stopping the wheel, you can get just as many chances at the lower levels too.

-With Crazy Orders your best bet is to play as the character you are trying to get moves for. And the best bet for getting those moves is to actually face Crazy Hand and collect as many treasure chests against him as possible. It seems like you are much more likely to get moves from him than you are from the tickets. So once you get to a point where your health percentage is too high, or you just don't see any tickets that seem easy enough to beat, go ahead and face Crazy Hand just to make sure you get the chance to.

With characters that I'm not very good with, I usually try to hold out until at least 8-9 tickets just to try to get moves from the tickets as well. If you are trying to get moves for characters that you are good with, you should be able to make it into the 15-20 range and getting that far will will give you much higher odds of getting moves. But it starts to get a bit harder around ticket 10, so if your character isn't that good, just go ahead and fight the hand to make sure you get the chance to.

However, if you are lucky and you get a new move on the first or second ticket, go ahead and face Crazy Hand right away. He should be extremely easy that early on, and beating him will guarantee that you don't lose the move.

If you do beat the hand, you also get an additional reward for the character that you KOed the most. Most of the time it is just equipment, but sometimes it is a custom move. However, the characters appear randomly, so it is difficult to try to pick who that character is. I tried it once looking for Wario moves and in 12 rounds Wario only showed up once. Some other characters had fought me 3-4 times, so I had no chance of getting something for him that time. Basically, trying to find them as opponents is not a very reliable strategy.

Answer (score 0):

If you do special orders with a horrible character and a home run bat mod, you can get through lots of rounds with its instant death characteristic. While many of the items are for other characters, there are quite a few for the character you played as.