# What is the best, fastest, and most consistent way to get custom moves/badges with perks?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

What is the best, fastest, and most consistent way to get custom moves/badges with perks in Smash 4, (3DS and Wii U)? Is there a way to only get badges with perks? Is there a way to not get gold or trophies? Let me know the best, fastest and most reliable ways to do so.

Comment: Generally, if you want help, it's a good idea to try to fit in and listen to the rules.  All we did was make your question more readable; beyond that, it'll take patience to get your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want more stuff in general, you're looking for [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/194164/fastest-way-to-unlock-custom-special-moves?rq=1), for which the answer is basically "it depends on what you like to do".

If you want only custom moves and equipment without getting any money or trophies, too bad, it's not possible (outside exceptional luck with the spinner in Classic Mode).

Comment: O.K. Well I didn't know that. In that case, what's the best way to get custom moves and badges with perks?